# Calculate order total price in node js and mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I built an ordering system with Node JS and MongoDB, I want to calculate order `total_price` in server before save it as a new order,

```
let ref = (model) => {
  return { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: model };
};
```

this is my `order` model schema

```
{
  items: [
    {
      id: ref("menu_item"),
      count: String,
      size: String,
      options: [String],
    },
  ],
  total_price: String,
  tip: String,
};
```

and this is `menu_item` model schema

```
{
  name: String,
  price: String,
  vat: String, // 3%
  size: [
    {
      name: String,
      unit: String,
      price: String,
      vat: String, // 3%
      in_stock: Boolean,
      is_default: Boolean,
    },
  ],
  options: [
    {
      title: String,
      options: [
        {
          name: String,
          price: String,
          vat: String, // 3%
          in_stock: Boolean,
          is_default: Boolean,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

How it's possible?
this is some tried that I done but it's wrong way.

when customer send an order this function will be call

```
async (req, res) => {
      let total = 0;
      let size_price = 0;
      let options_price = 0;
      
      let {
        items,
        tip,
      } = req.body;

      let price = 0;
      let item_price = items.forEach(async (el) => {
        let menu_item = await req.models.menu_item.findOne({ _id: el.id });
        price += parseInt(menu_item.price);
        console.log(menu_item.price) // first 12 second 9
        console.log(price) // first 12 second 21
      });
      

      console.log(price) // return 0
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forEach` loop does not wait for async functions to complete before executing next iteration / exiting the loop. In order to wait till all records are queried from DB and `price` value is updated, we can either wrap all promises in `Promise.all` or execute them serially in `for-of` loop.

Here is the updated code using `Promise.all`:

```
async (req, res) => {
      let total = 0;
      let size_price = 0;
      let options_price = 0;
      
      let {
        items,
        tip,
      } = req.body;

      let price = 0;
      await Promise.all(items.map(async (el) => {
          let menu_item = await req.models.menu_item.findOne({ _id: el.id });
          price += parseInt(menu_item.price);
          console.log(menu_item.price) // first 12 second 9
          console.log(price) // first 12 second 21
        })
      );
      

      console.log(price) // return 0
}
```