# Finally block execute before the end of try block

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

**Context :**

I have a discord bot running on discord.js and I recently created a MongoDB database to store some elements that I could use sometime in the futur.
I want to retrieve all the members of a specific discord "guild" and put them into individual MongoDB documents.

**What I do :**

First, I fetch those members with :

```js
const members = await testGuild.members.fetch();
```

This returns me a "Discord.Collection" object which is essentially a Map object.

Then I connect to my MongoDB using mongoose and I create a new document for each member of my members collection using :

```
await mongo().then(async mongoose => {
        try {
            members.each(async member => {
                const {user} = member
                await discordUserSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
                    _id: user.id
                }, {
                    _id: user.id,
                    username: user.username,
                    discriminator: user.discriminator,
                    avatar: user.avatar,
                    bot: user.bot
                }, {
                    upsert: true
                });
            });
        } finally {
            mongoose.connection.close();
        }
    });
```

My problem is that the finally block is executing before my try block is finished and I get this error :

```
(node:25008) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: server is closed
```

If I remove the try/finally blocks, I don't have any errors and the documents are correctly added to my collection but this is not the right way...

I also tried to connect to my database **inside** my each loop but it's awful because it opens then closes a connection for each member that I add to the collection and eventually, I get a timeout error.

What am I missing right here? Why the finally block executes this soon? Is that because of the async function inside my loop? How can I handle this differently?

Thanks.

Comment: try `await Promise.all(members.each(async ...` wait, that's assuming `.each` returns the array of promises...it might not. You might need something more like `members.map` if it exists. Anyway, one way or another you need to await on all those promises.

Comment: @David784 `await Promise.all` won't help in that case. It's not `Array.prototype.map`.

Comment: @David784 Thanks! You put me in the right track and then AlexZeDim gave me the full answer! Have a great day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `.each` function of `discord.js`, which is a copy of [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and won't wait, you might saw [a relevant case in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66128008/calculate-order-total-price-in-node-js-and-mongodb), for example.

So, to solve your problem with `try/catch/finally` and synchronous code, you'll need to use:

```js
for (const member of members) {
  /** 
   * your async/await logic
   * if you want it one by one
   */
}
```

or

```
await Promise.all(members.map(async member => {
  /** 
   * await logic here 
   * if you want all at once in parallel
   */
}));
```

And as mentioned before. If your application creates the connection with MongoDB just once at the start, don't open/close a new one for each time when you need something from the DB, just use the old one.

Comment: Well, thank you sir! This is exactly the explanation I needed. I went for the second option and it's all good now. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://dev.to/annarankin/finally-in-promises--trycatch-2c44) will help you out.
TLDR; Don't use try catch in that `.then()`, just use the `catch` and `finally` already usable with the `.then()`